# code to prove that hashMap is fail-Safe

Tags: java, collections

Question Edited :
HashSet and HashMap are fail-fast(but that is not gauranteed) as mentioned in code :

```
void goHashSet() {
        Set set = new HashSet();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            set.add(i);
        }
        Iterator i = set.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            // set.add(16);//Exception in thread "main"
            // java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
            System.out.println("HashSet >>> itertor >>>" + i.next());
        }
    }
```

Now, i want the example and the collections which are fail-safe
as much as i know: ConcurrentHashMap,CopyOnWriteArrayList are fail-safe..but how to code it to show that they are fail-safe

**Edit and Undestanding of what I want and how I achieved it :**

if we use HashMap

```
void goHashMap() {
        Map mp = new HashMap();
        for (int i = 19; i <= 24; i++) {
            mp.put(i, "x");
        }
        Set setKeys = mp.keySet();
        Iterator i = setKeys.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            // mp.put(499, "x");// Exception in thread "main"
            // java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
            System.out.println("HashMap >>> itertor >>>" + i.next());
        }
    }
```

we get ConcurrentMException

but the same code is done with ConcurrentHashMap, no error is there (non-multithreading enviro)

```
void goConcurrentHashMap() {
    Map mp = new ConcurrentHashMap();
    for (int i = 19; i <= 24; i++) {
        mp.put(i, "x");
    }
    Set setKeys = mp.keySet();
    Iterator i = setKeys.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        mp.put(499, "x");
        System.out.println("HashConcurrentMap >>> itertor >>>" + i.next());
    }
}
```

whats more : in multithreading enviro the ConcurrentHashmap might get fail-fast and throw exception CME

Comment: *"I understand what is fail-safe/fast is"* - based, on your question, I'm not sure that you do ... really.

Comment: @StephenC hmm,you might be right...but i have edited the question altogether...and whole purpose of the question is to see an example of fail-fast in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API Javadoc (both for [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) and [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)) only makes a soft guarantee to fail-safety:

> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast iterators throw `ConcurrentModificationException` on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: *the fail-fast behavior of iterators should be used only to detect bugs*.

The identical behaviour is explained by the fact that `HashSet` is implemented on top of a `HashMap` internally.

Feel free to check out the source code, bundled with your JDK installation though.

#### Update

> Now, i want the example and the collections which are fail-safe

Have a look at the collections in the `java.util.concurrent` package.

> as much as i know: ConcurrentHashMap,CopyOnWriteArrayList are fail-safe..but how to code it to show that they are fail-safe

The nature of concurrency is such that **it is impossible to prove thread-safety (or fail-safety) by tests alone**. You can only prove the opposite, i.e. that a specific class is not thread-safe (if that happens to be the case). This is exactly what makes concurrency hard.

The closest to proving such things is thorough analysis of the code in question by one or more concurrency experts. Some static analysis tools can spot some issues too, but again, a clean static analysis result is no guarantee.

Comment: ...thanks for the info and leting me know that HashMap also comes in fail-fast(but not gauranted) category like Vector,ArrayList etc

Comment: @jain007, I extended my post to answer your updated question.

Answer (score 2):

HashMap is not **guarenteed** to be fail safe.  You can still modify a HashMap in a different thread and have another thread not notice. The OpenJDK version of HashMap uses a non-`volatile` modcount field to identify concurrent modifications. As non-volatile fields are not guarenteed to be consistent between threads, one thread can change this and another thread fail to notice its changed.

This is a race condition which is relatively rare so it highly likely that a CME will be detected, but even if you test it and it behaves as expected 10000 times in a row, this don't provide the proof you might be looking for.

In fact its possible to write code which will pass the first 10000 times and consistently fail after that.  This is because the HotSpot compile will compile to native code after this point. This means code which runs ok before being optimised can behave differently after being optimised. esp for non volatile fields.

Comment: thanks for correcting me ...i have changed the question altogether to know the answer to my actual query...

Comment: You need to read the code to prove they are fail safe.  As I have pointed out, you cannot write a test which proves code is fail safe because it can always fail in ways the test doesn't test. e.g. OpenJDK and IBM J9 have different memory models so what works on one might not work on the other even for the same code and hardware.

Answer (score 0):

As if we see the internal implementation of ConcurrentHashMap it is very clearly mentioned that it works on the clone of original collection instead of original collection.

So, ideally your original collection is same as initial ... so this way we can say that ConcurrentHashMap avoids the COncurrentModifcationException and can be called as failsafe.

I tried to test it by creating a test programs where multiple threads was trying to modify my map .. I ran the test around 10 times and not even a single time it throws ConcurrentModification exception.

If we go more in detail implementation of ConcurentHashMap ... we will find that the synchronization mechanism is very much different from normal hashmap ... as CHM works on the algorithm segmentation lock.